# Book about a man putting his consciousness into his ship

Tags: story-identification

The book is about a war between humans and an alien species set in the future.  In the book a pilot merges his mind with a ship. So he can fly the ship and leave his body behind.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a fairly common trope in SF.  Can you remember any specific details, or a time-frame that it might have been published, or at least, that you read/first heard about it?

Comment: What kind of ship? Is it a ***space*** ship?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42706/sci-fi-story-where-a-pilot-transfers-his-consciousness-into-his-ship-and-explore?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly Gordon R. Dickson's [*Forever Man.*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GXN7MU4)

from the Amazon link above:

> The ancient starship La Chasse Gallerie is found drifting perilously
>   in space. Despite heavy damage from alien Laagi warships, incredibly
>   the ship is still intact and the voice of its pilot, Raoul Penard,
>   comes through loud and clear. But Penard died over one hundred years
>   ago. On Earth, frantic investigation reveals that Penard may be dead
>   but his mind is very much alive - *merged with the ship itself.* The
>   staggering potential of this evolutionary breakthrough compels the
>   scientists to embark on a technological journey of astonishing
>   discovery.

[image]

Comment: I have this book marked to get and read.  I think this maybe it.

Comment: Glad to help. It's a fairly good read, as I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Larry Niven wrote "A TearDrop Falls" set in Saberhagen's Berserker universe. Your question has elements that are similar to this.

You can read the book online [here](ftp://ftp.seti.org/phillips/scifi/A%20Teardrop%20Falls%20-%20Larry%20Niven.txt)

Comment: Ah... is there some license for that work that has been obtained by SETI for providing it for download? IANAL but I'm sure Niven still holds the copyright for that work.

Comment: Can you describe what elements are similar...?

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it was not one by Niven.  He is one of my favorite authors.

Answer (score 1):

It may be one of the novels from *Anne McCaffery's* **Brainship** series.

> The concept brainship in science fiction literature refers to an interstellar starship that is created by inserting the disembodied brain and nervous system of a human being into a life-support system, and connecting it surgically to a series of computers via delicate synaptic connections (a brain-computer interface.) The brain "feels" the ship (or any other connected peripherals) as part of its own body. Flying, taking off, landing, and controlling all the other features of the ship are as natural as moving, breathing and talking are to an ordinary human. Being wired into a computer speeds their reactions, but still allows their human brains to make intelligent decisions based on calculations.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainship)

> The Brain & Brawn Ship series comprises seven novels, only the first of which (a fix-up of five previously published stories) was written by McCaffrey alone.[49] The stories in this series deal with the adventures of "shell-people" or "Brains", who as infants (due to illness or birth defects) have had to be hard-wired into a life-support system. With sensory input and motor nerves tied into a computer they serve as starship pilots (or colony administrators), seeing and feeling the colony or ship as an extension of their own body. They perform this job to pay off their debt for education and hardware, and continue as free agents once the debt is paid. To compensate for the Brains' inability to move within human habitats they are paired with partners known as "Brawns", who are trained in a wide array of skills (including the protection of their Brain counterparts). It was considered impossible for a person to adjust to being a shell after the age of two or three. An exception, in The Ship Who Searched, was a shell-person who was seven when she became quadriplegic.

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_McCaffrey#The_Brain_.26_Brawn_Ship_series)

List of novels in the series -

- **The Ship Who Sang** (1969) (fix-up of stories from 1961, 1966, and 1969)
- **PartnerShip** (1992) with Margaret Ball
- **The Ship Who Searched** (1992) with Mercedes Lackey
- **The City Who Fought** (1993) with S.M. Stirling
- **The Ship Who Won** (1994) with Jody Lynn Nye
- This series also includes solo entries by Stirling and Nye
- **The Ship Errant** (1996) by Jody Lynn Nye
- **The Ship Avenged** (1997) by S.M. Stirling

A link to the series on good reads - https://www.goodreads.com/series/40397-brainship

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it was not this series.  Actually that series is one of my favorites.

Comment: @John Well it was worth a mention!! But truly there are a number out there that have people of parts of people or expeople and spaceships. I do think I may have seen the book you are looking for (didn't read though) in a review.... This is as close as I came to finding it! :) Hope you find your novel!

Comment: Thanks I do believe I have. But my reading list is so long not sure when I will get to it.

Comment: @John As long as you found it!!